# Notation of fitted ARMA-GARCH model

Tags: time-series, fitting, garch, notation

I am working on ARMA+GARCH and wonder what the correct notation for a fitted model is. For example, my model is a jointly estimated AR(1)-GARCH(1,1) model with
mean equation 
$$
r_t = 0.034 r_{t-1} + 0.0075 + a_t
$$ 
and volatility equation 
$$
\sigma_t^2 = 0.0000794 + 0.122 a_{t-1}^2 + 0.855 \sigma_{t-1}^2.
$$

Should I write 
\begin{aligned}
r_t &= 0.034 r_{t-1} + 0.0075 + \hat{a}_t, \text{ where} \\ 
\hat{a}_t &= \hat{\sigma}_t \epsilon_t \text{ and} \\ 
\hat{\sigma}_t^2 &= 0.0000794 + 0.122 \hat{a}_{t-1}^2 + 0.855 \hat{\sigma}_{t-1}^2? \\
\end{aligned}

Or 
\begin{aligned}
\hat{r_t} &= 0.034 r_{t-1} + 0.0075 \text{ and} \\ 
\hat{\sigma}_t^2 &= 0.0000794 + 0.122 \hat{a}_{t-1}^2 + 0.855 \hat{\sigma}_{t-1}^2? \\
\end{aligned}

Are these notations both correct? I think in the second notation the connection of both equations is not really clear.

Thanks for clarification.